# How to fetch complete cookies detail in WKWebView in IOS

Tags: ios, swift

In my app **there is a login page on Webview and url is based on https**. I want to get login username and password from cookies. But not able to fetch it

I tried **[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]** it just send me other cookies details like domain,creation time,etc but not providing detail which user enter at the time of login.
If anyone has an idea about it please help in it.

Answer (score 0):

So you are doing like user will login from UIWebView and it will login to the application.

If this is the case, then username and password related cookie should be saved from web page through web-developer. Also cookie name should be known.

So, when page will be reload, you need to check cookie that user is logged in or not. (this will be set from server side). For e.g. "isLogin" cookie is set to "1" then you can check with other cookie of "username" and "password" (which is also set from server side) and you can login to the app.

Thank you.

Comment: Web developer provided me key for username and password but not fetching using method while android developer is able to fetch and it's working in his side. I tried with  [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]

Comment: When android developer are able to fetch username and password? I think when UIWebView page is refreshed then you need to recheck the cookie and if it is set then you can get those values. Please compare the cookie fetch methods with android and let me know.

Comment: It's not possible to fetch secure credentials from cookies. So i tried with javascript evaluation and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

with ios 11 we can use WKWebsiteDataStore

```
extension WKWebView {

private var httpCookieStore: WKHTTPCookieStore  {
    return WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore
}

func getCookies(for domain: String? = nil, completion: @escaping ([String : Any])->())  {
    var cookieDict = [String : AnyObject]()
    httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
        for cookie in cookies {
            if let domain = domain {
                if cookie.domain.contains(domain) {
                    cookieDict[cookie.name] = cookie.properties as AnyObject?
                }
            } else {
                cookieDict[cookie.name] = cookie.properties as AnyObject?
            }
        }
        completion(cookieDict)
    }
}
}
```